# H2O can not subset columns from the H2OParsedData

Tags: r, hadoop, h2o

I use h2o(2.8.4.4) for hadoop from R.
I want to get some column from the data frame with 720512 rows and 788 columns.
I write something like this:

```
library("h2o");
localH2O = h2o.init(ip = ipItem, port = 54321, startH2O = F)
waterTrain <- h2o.importFile(localH2O, path=trainName, key="trainKey", parse=T, header=T, sep="*")
subset <- waterTrain[, 1:787]
Error: Expectation failed
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert waterTrain to a data frame using as.data.frame method and later you filter (subset) conveniently using standard R methods

```
waterTrain.data.frame <- as.data.frame(waterTrain)
```

Alternatively you can also,

```
irisPath <- system.file("extdata", "iris.csv", package="h2o")
iris.hex <- h2o.importFile(localH2O, path = irisPath, key = "iris.hex")
iris.hex.top10 <- iris.hex[1:10,1:3]
```

Comment: thank you for your help. But I want to use `h2o.gbm`. It works only with h2o parsed data. And I get there the same error.